# yii pass data in between two models

Tags: php, session, yii, session-variables

how is it possible to pass data in between two models.

i have model called Search and Activity.

after a logic happen in Search i need a value to be stored in a session and after words when i access the session via Activity model i should get that stored value in session.

```
$activities = Activity::model()->findAll($criteria);
         foreach ($activities as $val)
            $matchingActs[] = $val->id;
```

i added it the below way (creating session) Search Model

```
Yii::app()->session['ActivitiesId'] = $matchingActs;
```

used it in Activity as following..

```
print_r(Yii::app()->session['ActivitiesId']); exit();
```

this doesnt work and i am thinking weather i should use getState and setState.

confused with two models data passing

OUTPUT is as below..

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 9 [2] => 3 [3] => 16 [4] => 8 [5] => 5 [6] => 4 [7] => 11 [8] => 1 [9] => 10 [10] => 13 [11] => 15 [12] => 14 [13] => 7 [14] => 17 [15] => 18 [16] => 12 [17] => 6 [18] => 19 [19] => 24 [20] => 25 )
```

but actually insert only this array.. but something else as above only comes up.

```
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 25 )  // $matchingActs
```

**EDIT 1**

Used setState and getState but still its outputting the same. i am confused why this strange behavior from yii

var_dump results are below inside **SEARCH** model.. // var_dump($matchingActs);

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '24' (length=2)
  1 => string '25' (length=2)
```

//Yii::app()->user->setState('globalunit',$matchingActs);

```
array (size=2) // var_dump(Yii::app()->user->getState('globalunit'));
  0 => string '24' (length=2)
  1 => string '25' (length=2)
```

Now in **Activity** if i do the same, // var_dump(Yii::app()->user->getState('globalunit'));

```
array (size=21)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '9' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '16' (length=2)
  4 => string '8' (length=1)
  5 => string '5' (length=1)
  6 => string '4' (length=1)
  7 => string '11' (length=2)
  8 => string '1' (length=1)
  9 => string '10' (length=2)
  10 => string '13' (length=2)
  11 => string '15' (length=2)
  12 => string '14' (length=2)
  13 => string '7' (length=1)
  14 => string '17' (length=2)
  15 => string '18' (length=2)
  16 => string '12' (length=2)
  17 => string '6' (length=1)
  18 => string '19' (length=2)
  19 => string '24' (length=2)
  20 => string '25' (length=2)
```

Comment: What kind of data is `$matchingActs`?

Comment: @Pitchinnate tnx for quick reply. pls check the question again. i have added the input and output. $matchingActs is an array.

Comment: @Pitchinnate is it possible to pass a object too this way?

Comment: Yii has known issues with storing arrays https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1681 check out my answer on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519156/yii-manipulating-a-sesssion-variable#comment27235746_18519156

Comment: @Pitchinnate ok tnx. is my expectation is something possible to achieve or not ? :-|

Comment: Yeah you can store whatever you want with `setState` and `getState` and access at anytime and in any controller, model or view.

Comment: @Pitchinnate ok but i am getting the same results. check the edited section in the question..

Comment: Can you do a `print_r` or `var_dump` on `$matchingActs`?

Comment: yes... ok i am updating the question now. pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that PHP doesn't allow that much long size of data in single session variable. You can solve it using CDBSession implemented in Yii to take care of PHP limitation. This is how you use it.

In your **config** under component

```
            'session'=>array(

                    'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',

            ),
```

Now you can add any data into it like this-

```
Yii::app()->session->add('name','value');
```

And use it just like this-

```
echo Yii::app()->session['test'];
```

Give it a try.

Cheers

Comment: can you provide extended code, that may help to understand whats going on, for now try json_encode and json_decode for saving data in session. May it help. If dont post the extended code. Ok